# adding a default note to powerpoint

Tags: powerpoint

I want to modify powerpoint so that the notes section always contains a static text. specifically I want to add

```
  <tags></tags>
```

to the notes section of every slide created. I was hoping for an easy way to to do this on the master slide, but so far Dr. Google hasn't shown me how. I tried just adding it to the Notes Master but that didn't work.

I'm open to programmatic solutions, but would rather have a settings based solution if it exists.

How do I add text to every slide's note section upon slide creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"notes section" could mean different things.  If you want some text to appear on every notes PAGE, where it'll appear on all printed notes, you just need to add it to the notes master.

If you want it to appear in the notes text that's part of every notes page (and also appears in the notes pane beneath the slide in Normal view), I don't think it's possible, at least not w/o having an installed add-in.

Answer (score 0):

I have researched this a lot as well, but there doesn't seem to be any way of adding predefined text to the Notes area under the slide in the Slide Master.

You can do it with a macro after the presentation is created. Instead of using "[tag]" & "[/tag]", you can use something easier to type like "/1" and "\1", then use the macro to find and replace your "numbered" tags with the text equivalents.

Something like this:

```
Dim aSlide as Slide
Dim noteShp as Shape

For each aSlide in ActivePresentation.Slides
  For Each noteShp In aSlide.NotesPage.Shapes
    If noteShp.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderBody Then
      If noteShp.HasTextFrame Then
        If noteShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
          noteShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(noteShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "/1", "<tag>")
          noteShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(noteShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "\1", "<\tag>")
         End if
      End If
     End If
   End If
  Next
Next
```

I am doing exactly the same thing as you are.

I use html style tags in the notes section (the area underneath the slide in **Normal** View) to organize information and automatically create supporting documentation for the presentation.

Right now, I am doing it by manually by pasting the tags into the Note area under each slide, but if anyone knows how to pre-populate the Note area each time a new slide is added (by modifying the Slide Master settings - ***not*** the Notes Master), that would be fantastic.

Looking forward to see if anyone has a solution to this!

Comment: In an add-in, you could trap the PresentationNewSlide event, which'd give you a reference to the newly inserted slide. From that you could reference the Notes page and add whatever text you like.